# Saving randomly generated discount coupons into Mongodb using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema for `Coupon` and `Product`. When a product is added using the API, certain `unit` of unique coupons will be created and inserted into the `Coupon` and references of those coupons should also be inserted inside the `Product`. I am using `coupon-code` package to generate the coupon.

```
let couponSchema = new Schema({
  code: {type: String, unique: true},
  status: {type:Boolean, default: false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Coupon', couponSchema);

let productSchema = new Schema({
  prductname: {type: String},
  unit: {type: Number},
  coupon: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Coupon}],
  category: {type: String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

This is a post API to add Products. I am able to save codes to the `Coupon` collection but confused on how to save recently added coupon references to `Product`.

```
api.post('/add', (req, res, next) => {
  let newProduct = new Product();

  newProduct.productname = req.body.productname;
  newProduct.unit = req.body.unit;
  newProduct.category = req.body.category;

  var i;
  for(i=0; i<=req.body.unit; i++){
    var code = ucg.generate(); // ucg is imported from coupon-code package
    let newCoupon = new Coupon();
    newCoupon.code = code;
    newCoupon.save(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error occured");
        return;
      }
    });
  }
  
  newProduct.save(err => {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
      return;
    }
    res.json({message: "Product added successfully."});
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me find out a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `push` method `newProduct.coupon.push(newCoupon.id);`

```
for(i=0; i<=req.body.unit; i++){
    var code = ucg.generate(); // ucg is imported from coupon-code package
    let newCoupon = new Coupon();
    newCoupon.code = code;
    newCoupon.save(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error occured");
        return;
      }
    });
    newProduct.coupon.push(newCoupon.id);
  }
```